# Ubuntu 11.04 DUAL monitor issue

Tags: multiple-monitors

Hello I have a laptop 15' and was going to use 23' external monitor.

I attached it and they both were working fine. But what I wanted is
just to use only one monitor and leave laptop's display to be turned off.

I couldn't find a way to do it and after playing with settings I turned first monitor off
hoping that system decides to use the second one as main monitor.

However they both are now showing black.

I am having to detach my second monitor and restart my machine (from another terminal's console)

What I want..is just turn laptops monitor off and use 23' one when it's attached.

I would also be quite happy if you would tell me where does Ubuntu store settings about monitors.

I also would to at least to be able to use two monitors at the same time (i.e revoke my last change)

Comment: okay! I've found it in ~/.config/monitors.xml
Just deleted that file and I reverted my changes.

Comment: Now I'm trying to make my second monitor to be default (main) monitor and leave laptop's monitor turned off.

Comment: So I drag and dropped the second monitor behind the laptop's monitor in Monitors tool and things seem worked. But I encountered another issues like the Dash is showing only on Laptop's display (when you press the Win key) also I'm seeing a black rectangle on the bottom and can't resize the window to have it bigger than 1600px (the width of frist monitor)

Comment: Set the external monitor as primary in minitors.xml but things are not showing good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on 11.04 type `monitor` on unity launcher

Then you will see your monitors like this

[image]

If you want to turned of the laptop screen and use the external one jsut select the laptop monitor and then click on `Off` radio button.  then click on `apply`

like this:
[image]

Now you have only the external monitor.

**Update** - Replying to the comment below.

You should remove  `~/.config/monitors.xml` and try again.

Comment: yes, I did exactly this. both monitors went off.

Comment: I also drag and dropped the second monitor behind the laptop and things seem worked. But I encountered another issues like the Dash is showing only on Laptop's display (when you press the Win key) also I'm seeing a black rectangle on the bottom and can't resize the window to have it bigger than 1600px (the width of frist monitor)

Comment: If you turned off the laptop monitor, the launcher doesn't show up on the external monitor?

Comment: If I turn the laptop monitor off...all monitors are black and impossible to work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and google led me here. I was able to solve the problem by deleting `~/.config/monitors.xml` and then used the display settings to turn laptop monitor off. And it worked.