# Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 LTS hangs with dual display

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors

I upgraded my Ubuntu 11.04 Oneric to the latest version Ubuntu 12.04 LTS this morning, but after installing all upgrades & cleaning up (Upgradation steps), when it restarted first time to complete installation, it got hang. Then I removed VGA cable of external display attached to my laptop & did a hard reboot then booted successfully and again when I connected other display, it got stuck again.

NOTE: I did upgrade to 12.04 LTS with 2nd display connected & that combo was working well with 11.04 Oneric.

Comment: As suggested here http://askubuntu.com/questions/55326/latest-ubuntu-dual-monitor-issue I deleted my ~/.config/monitors.xml file. Now it came up with clone display working.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and the "fix" for this is to revert back to an older version of xserver-xorg-input-evdev until a proper fix is implemented.

1. Download the following two packages to your desktop:

[`xserver-xorg-input-evdev-udeb_2.6.99.901-1ubuntu3~lp921236_amd64.udeb`](https://launchpad.net/~sarvatt/+archive/sru1/+build/3118994/+files/xserver-xorg-input-evdev-udeb_2.6.99.901-1ubuntu3~lp921236_amd64.udeb) (24.0 KiB)

[`xserver-xorg-input-evdev_2.6.99.901-1ubuntu3~lp921236_amd64.deb`](https://launchpad.net/~sarvatt/+archive/sru1/+build/3118994/+files/xserver-xorg-input-evdev_2.6.99.901-1ubuntu3~lp921236_amd64.deb) (38.0 KiB)

1. Open a terminal and execute:

   `cd Desktop`

   `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`
2. Restart your computer or if you are lazy just restart the X Server with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>PRINTSCREEN|SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

Comment: Original blog post: http://blog.shevin.info/2012/05/how-to-fix-dual-monitor-freeze-in.html

Comment: Launchpad bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/992778

Comment: Wouldn't the `dpkg` command not process the first file as it has a different file extension?

Comment: Be careful suggesting sudo dpkg -i *.deb. 
The user may have some deb files on desktop.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having AMD graphics, I would suggest you to do a clean install rather than the upgrade, I too  have a dual monitor setup. Also use your Catalyst settings to setup dual display,Use the open source driver,It will be better and I  hope you won't face any more problem after that.